# is there any way to request for client zone base data retrieval from angular app to django?

Tags: django, angular, django-models, django-rest-framework, angular8

while interacting from angular 8 app to django back end i want to retrieve data based on user timezone without doing any manual conversion between the timezone . Date being saved is in UTC format on backend. in which format date should be sent so that it automatically retrieve correct data for that zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn time at back-end into a string and then, front-end you get string time from back-end. you use rest API?